# How to show only text from post in WordPress

Tags: get-posts, formatting

How do I retrieve just the text of a post in WordPress not including any pictures?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the wordpress theme to do this. If you know how to do this, all you need to do is replace the_content(); with this below:

`<?php
ob_start();

the_content('Read the full post',true);

$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());

ob_end_clean();

echo $postOutput; ?>`

And all images will be removed from your posts.